# How can I implement the side alphabetic view in apple's music app in swift? Which used to sort the items in the list in alphabetic order

Tags: ios, swift

I have implemented a list of items using a collection view and I want have a similar "side alphabetic view" as in the Apple Music app, so that I can scroll through the items in my list alphabetically.

| Apple Music app | My app so far |
| --- | --- |
| [image: Apple music app with the menu containing the letters in order to sort my music] | [image: Collection view without side alphabetic view] |

Answer (score 2):

In your collection view data source, implement the methods [`indexTitles(for:)`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uicollectionviewdatasource/2851455-indextitles) and [`collectionView(_:indexPathForIndexTitle:at:)`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uicollectionviewdatasource/2851456-collectionview).

Comment: Thank you for the response. I would be grateful if you could elaborate more on your answer as I am a beginner to swift. I understand how to get the above two methods you have mentioned but I don't know how to use it exactly. I read the documentation but I'm unable to understand it. @Vym